# Get crl expiration date from command line

Tags: c#, c++, powershell, ca

I’m fairly new to PowerShell and I don’t how to pull this off.

I need to check if the Root CA’s CRL is about to expire but there is no cmdlet for doing so in the built-in PowerShell modules [pki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) or [ADCSAdministration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adcsadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) in the Sub CA.

**NB: It’s a two-tier PKI and the Root CA is offline most of the time.**

Getting the CRL was the easy part: reading its properties from a script not so much.

I’m aware of the cmdlet [Get-CertificateRevocationList](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSPKI/3.7.2/Content/Client%5CGet-CertificateRevocationList.ps1) from the PowerShell module [PSPKI](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSPKI/3.7.2), unfortunately, I cannot rely on third party code for this.

Searching for an answer I’ve found the [CertVerifyCRLTimeValidity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certverifycrltimevalidity) function but I don’t know how to make it work.

**NB: the Microsoft documentation offers code snippets only in C++ but PowerShell takes in only C#.**

[Call native Windows APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-5.1#example-4-call-native-windows-apis)

```
$MemberDefinition =
@"
public struct _FILETIME {
  DWORD dwLowDateTime;
  DWORD dwHighDateTime;
} FILETIME, *PFILETIME, *LPFILETIME;

public struct _CRL_INFO {
  DWORD                      dwVersion;
  CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER SignatureAlgorithm;
  CERT_NAME_BLOB             Issuer;
  FILETIME                   ThisUpdate;
  FILETIME                   NextUpdate;
  DWORD                      cCRLEntry;
  PCRL_ENTRY                 rgCRLEntry;
  DWORD                      cExtension;
  PCERT_EXTENSION            rgExtension;
} CRL_INFO, *PCRL_INFO;

[DllImport("Crypt32.dll")]public static extern long CertVerifyCRLTimeValidity(LPFILETIME 
pTimeToVerify, PCRL_INFO  pCrlInfo);
"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MemberDefinition -Name 'CertVerifyCRLTimeValidity'
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I think I would just write a small C++ exe that would accept one or  more commandline arguments and return 0 or 1. This return value can then be used from errorlevel in your script.

Comment: @PepijnKramer : thanks for your answer but I'm trying to avoid third-party solutions or any other dependencies, such as compiled executable files.