# How to convert FILETIME to DATETIME in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, ca

[In reference to one of my topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857213/get-crl-expiration-date-from-command-line/72969184#72969184)

The solution I’m trying to implement will run in Windows Server through PowerShell, in other words, with .NET Framework behind the scenes.

In the absence of any specific cmdlet in Microsoft's [PKI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) module, I’ve been looking for native Windows functions that could perform the operations and I’ve found them in the headers [wincrypt.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/), [timezoneapi.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/), [minwinbase.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/).

The code snippets in the Microsoft documentation are written in C++; therefore, converting [Managed Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/managed-types-cpp-cli?view=msvc-170#dotnet) and other [Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/432cd7e7-6276-4c82-87fc-50bbcbd5ffa0) to C# is required to integrate functions and structures into the PowerShell script.

Unfortunately, every attempt to interact with properties or parameters of the FILETIME type have failed.

I’ve tried different starting points in time, but the results are still not the ones expected

```
$PowerShell = [DateTime]::new(0001,1,1,0,0,0,[System.DateTimeKind]::Utc) 
$FileTime = [DateTime]::new(1601,1,1,0,0,0,[System.DateTimeKind]::Utc) 
$UnixEpoch = [DateTime]::new(1970,1,1,0,0,0,[System.DateTimeKind]::Utc)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to properly convert **FILETIME** to **DATETIME**?

```
$Cryptnet =  
@' 
[DllImport("Cryptnet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
public static extern bool CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl 
( 
        string pszUrl, 
        uint   pszObjectOid, 
        uint   dwRetrievalFlags, 
        uint   dwTimeout, 
    ref IntPtr ppvObject, 
        IntPtr hAsyncRetrieve, 
        IntPtr pCredentials, 
        IntPtr pvVerify, 
        IntPtr pAuxInfo 
); 
'@ 

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Cryptnet -Name Cryptnet -Namespace Win32 

$Crypt32 =  
@' 
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
public static extern bool CertFreeCRLContext 
( 
    IntPtr pCrlContext 
); 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct CRL_CONTEXT 
{ 
    public uint      dwCertEncodingType; 
    public IntPtr    pbCrlEncoded; 
    public uint      cbCrlEncoded; 
    public IntPtr    pCrlInfo; 
    public IntPtr    hCertStore; 
}; 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct CRL_INFO 
{ 
    public uint                                             dwVersion; 
    public IntPtr                                           SignatureAlgorithm; 
    public IntPtr                                           Issuer; 
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ThisUpdate; 
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME NextUpdate; 
    public uint                                             cCRLEntry; 
    public IntPtr                                           rgCRLEntry; 
    public uint                                             cExtension; 
    public IntPtr                                           rgExtension; 
}; 
'@ 

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Crypt32 -Name Crypt32 -Namespace Win32 

<# 
# if the ThisUpdate and NextUpdate properties of the CRL_INFO struct are declared as IntPtr, the FILETIME struct is required to convert the pointers to the underlying structure.  

$Kernel32 =  
@' 
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)] 
public struct FILETIME 
{ 
  public uint dwLowDateTime; 
  public uint dwHighDateTime; 
}; 
'@ 

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Kernel32 -Name Kernel32 -Namespace Win32 
#> 

$pszUrl           = 'http://pki.contoso.com/cadp/Contoso-RootCA.crl'                  # [...] The address of a PKI object to be retrieved. [...] 
$pszObjectOid     = 2                     # CONTEXT_OID_CRL 
$dwRetrievalFlags = 4                     # CRYPT_WIRE_ONLY_RETRIEVAL 
$dwTimeout        = 0                     # [...] If a value of zero is specified, this function does not time out. [...] 
$ppvObject        = [System.IntPtr]::Zero # [...] The address of a pointer to the returned object. [...] 
$hAsyncRetrieve   = [System.IntPtr]::Zero # [...] This parameter is reserved and must be set to NULL. [...] 
$pCredentials     = [System.IntPtr]::Zero # [...] This parameter is not used. [...] 
$pvVerify         = [System.IntPtr]::Zero # [...] It can be NULL to indicate that the caller is not interested in getting the certificate context or index of the signer [...] 
$pAuxInfo         = [System.IntPtr]::Zero # [...] If not NULL and if the cbSize member of the structure is set, this parameter returns the time of the last successful wire retrieval. [...] 

$CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl = [Win32.Cryptnet]::CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl( 
$pszUrl, 
$pszObjectOid, 
$dwRetrievalFlags, 
$dwTimeout, 
[ref]$ppvObject, 
$hAsyncRetrieve, 
$pCredentials, 
$pvVerify, 
$pAuxInfo 
) 

if ($CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl) 
{ 
    $CRL_CONTEXT = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStructure($ppvObject,[System.Type][Win32.Crypt32+CRL_CONTEXT]) 

    [System.Void][Win32.Crypt32]::CertFreeCRLContext($ppvObject) 

    $CRL_INFO = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStructure($CRL_CONTEXT.pCrlInfo,[System.Type][Win32.Crypt32+CRL_INFO])  

    $NextUpdate = [System.Int64]($CRL_INFO.NextUpdate.dwHighDateTime -shl 32) -bor [System.Int32]($CRL_INFO.NextUpdate.dwLowDateTime) 

    [System.DateTime]::FromFileTimeUtc($NextUpdate) 

    $ThisUpdate = ($CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwHighDateTime -shl 32) -bor ($CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwLowDateTime) 

    [System.DateTime]::FromFileTimeUtc($ThisUpdate) 

} 

else 
{ 
    $LastWin32Error = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error() 
    $Exception = Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\New-Object -TypeName System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception -ArgumentList $LastWin32Error 
    $ErrorId = 'CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl' 
    $ErrorCategory = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::NotSpecified 
    $TargetObject= $null 
    $ErrorRecord = Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord -ArgumentList 
    $Exception, 
    $ErrorId, 
    $ErrorCategory, 
    $TargetObject 

    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $ErrorRecord 
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you simply want `[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc($filetimeValue)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Unfortunately this doesn't cut it for me. The [DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc) method takes in an int64 argument and the FILETIME is either [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) or [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.filetime) made of two properties

Comment: Please take some time to reformat your code - and ideally reduce it to a minimal example. Currently you've posted 260 lines of code, but over half of those are blank lines...

Comment: @JonSkeet I've removed most of the blank lines as suggested but this is already the shorter version of the script: I've put in the question only the code related to it.

Comment: @Kanuc You know what you can make with two 32-bit integers? A 64-bit integer :) `$filetimeValue = [long]$highPart -shl 32 -bor $lowPart`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen If you look at the variables $NextUpdate and $ThisUpdate you'll see that I've already used what you are suggested:

`$NextUpdate = ($CRL_INFO.NextUpdate.dwHighDateTime -shl 32) -bor ($CRL_INFO.NextUpdate.dwLowDateTime)`

`$ThisUpdate = ($CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwHighDateTime -shl 32) -bor ($CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwLowDateTime)`

Comment: @Kanuc Yeah but you need to cast the first operand in the shift operation to `[long]`, otherwise you'll end up with a truncated value: `([long]$CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwHighDateTime -shl 32) -bor $CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwLowDateTime`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen My bad, the original line is:

`[System.Uint64]([System.Uint64]($CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwHighDateTime -shl 32) -bor [System.Int32]($CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate.dwLowDateTime))`

Comment: Why not scrap `FILETIME` altogether and just use `long`

Comment: @Charlieface As much as I’d like to, the object retrieved by the [CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptretrieveobjectbyurlw) holds the to properties I’m interested in as FILETIME.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand me: `FILETIME` is just two `int32` values, which can be replaces with a `long` which is 64 bits. So instead of `public ComTypes.FILETIME ThisUpdate;` you can use `public long ThisUpdate;`

Comment: @Charlieface after reading your last comment I went on wandering and I stumbled on this two Microsoft's blog articles: at this point, I'm not sure if I should do what you've suggested.

- [Why can’t you treat a FILETIME as an __int64?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040825-00/?p=38053)
- [I saw a pinvoke signature that passed a UInt64 instead of a FILETIME, what’s up with that?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150820-00/?p=91771)

Comment: Hmmm good point, forgot about alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the challenges of converting your `FILETIME` struct instances to `[long]` values, as required by the [`System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc) method, *in PowerShell code*, by instead providing the conversion as part of your ad hoc-compiled *C#* code:

```bash
$Kernel32 =  
@' 
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)] 
public struct FILETIME 
{ 
  public uint dwLowDateTime; 
  public uint dwHighDateTime; 
}; 

// Converts a FILETIME instance to a UTC DateTime instance
public static DateTime ToDateTime(FILETIME ft) {
  long ftAsLong = unchecked(
    (long)((ulong)ft.dwHighDateTime << 32 | ft.dwLowDateTime)
  );
  return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(ftAsLong);
}
'@ 

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Kernel32 -Name Kernel32 -Namespace Win32 

# Sample call

# Sample FILETIME value.
$ft = [Win32.Kernel32+FILETIME]::new(); 
$ft.dwLowDateTime = 4280342244;
$ft.dwHighDateTime = 30971996

# Convert to [datetime] (as a UTC time stamp; .Kind == Utc)
[Win32.Kernel32]::ToDateTime($ft)
```

You can provide an analogous method for the .NET [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME) value type, whose members are actually `int` (`Int32`)-typed.

Comment: @ mklement0 , Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I’ve slightly modified the function you’ve provided to take in a [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME?view=net-6.0) argument. To other looking for reference, please check this link: [FILETIME](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/FILETIME.html).