# Add proper p/invoke signature to PowerShell script

Tags: c#, c++, powershell

So far, I’ve managed to put together this code after getting guidance from this other post:

[How to convert FILETIME to DATETIME in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995116/how-to-convert-filetime-to-datetime-in-powershell)

```
$Cryptnet =  
@' 
[DllImport("Cryptnet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
public static extern bool CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl 
( 
    string pszUrl, 
    uint   pszObjectOid, 
    uint   dwRetrievalFlags, 
    uint   dwTimeout, 
ref IntPtr ppvObject, 
    IntPtr hAsyncRetrieve, 
    IntPtr pCredentials, 
    IntPtr pvVerify, 
    IntPtr pAuxInfo 
); 
'@ 

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Cryptnet -Name Cryptnet -Namespace Win32 

$Crypt32 =  
@' 
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
public static extern bool CertFreeCRLContext 
( 
     IntPtr pCrlContext 
);  

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct CRL_CONTEXT 
{ 
    public uint   dwCertEncodingType; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=2)] 
    public byte[] pbCrlEncoded; 
    public uint   cbCrlEncoded; 
    public IntPtr pCrlInfo; 
    public IntPtr hCertStore; 
}; 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct CRL_INFO 
{ 
    public uint                                             dwVersion; 
    public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER                       SignatureAlgorithm; 
    public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB                                   Issuer; 
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ThisUpdate; 
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME NextUpdate; 
    public uint                                             cCRLEntry; 
    public IntPtr                                           rgCRLEntry; 
    public uint                                             cExtension; 
    public IntPtr                                           rgExtension; 
}; 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER 
{ 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public String         pszObjId; 
    public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Parameters; 
}; 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB 
{ 
    public uint   cbData; 
    public IntPtr pbData; 
}; 
'@  

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Crypt32 -Name Crypt32 -Namespace Win32 

$Kernel32 =  
@' 
public static DateTime FileTimeToDateTime(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME FileTime) 
{ 
    long FileTimeUtc = (long)((((ulong)FileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32) | ((uint)FileTime.dwLowDateTime)); 
    return System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(FileTimeUtc); 
} 
'@ 

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Kernel32 -Name Kernel32 -Namespace Win32 

$pszUrl           = 'http://pki.contoso.com/cadp/Contoso-RootCA.crl' 
$pszObjectOid     = 2 
$dwRetrievalFlags = 4 
$dwTimeout        = 0 
$ppvObject        = [System.IntPtr]::Zero 
$hAsyncRetrieve   = [System.IntPtr]::Zero 
$pCredentials     = [System.IntPtr]::Zero 
$pvVerify         = [System.IntPtr]::Zero 
$pAuxInfo         = [System.IntPtr]::Zero 

$CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl = [Win32.Cryptnet]::CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl( 
                                                                            $pszUrl, 
                                                                            $pszObjectOid, 
                                                                            $dwRetrievalFlags, 
                                                                            $dwTimeout, 
                                                                       [ref]$ppvObject, 
                                                                            $hAsyncRetrieve, 
                                                                            $pCredentials, 
                                                                            $pvVerify, 
                                                                            $pAuxInfo 
                                                                      ) 
if ($CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl) 
{ 
    $CRL_CONTEXT = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStructure($ppvObject,[System.Type][Win32.Crypt32+CRL_CONTEXT]) 

    [System.Void][Win32.Crypt32]::CertFreeCRLContext($ppvObject) 

    $CRL_INFO = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStructure($CRL_CONTEXT.pCrlInfo,[System.Type][Win32.Crypt32+CRL_INFO]) 

    [Win32.Kernel32]::FiletimeToDateTime($CRL_INFO.ThisUpdate) 

    [Win32.Kernel32]::FiletimeToDateTime($CRL_INFO.NextUpdate) 
}
```

Unfortunately, I’m not able to properly declare the **CRL_CONTEXT** struct:
If I use this [snippet](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/CRL_CONTEXT.html), I get this error message:

> Exception calling "PtrToStructure" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot marshal field 'pbCrlEncoded' of type 'CRL_CONTEXT': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Array fields must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray)."

If I remove the following line of code from the '**pbCrlEncoded**' declaration, I get another error message:

> [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=2)]

> Exception calling "PtrToStructure" with "2" argument(s): "Mismatch has occurred between the runtime type of the array and the sub type recorded in the metadata."

If I change the type of the '**pbCrlEncoded**' from **byte[]** to **IntPtr**, I get no error message but the subsequent converted object makes no sense.

Can anyone please comment on how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? Do you have to use PInvoke?

Comment: As far as I can tell from a bunch of web searches, ```SizeParamIndex``` only applies to p/Invoke *methods*, not *fields* on structs, so it's basically being ignored (you get the same error if you remove it). This means the marshaler doesn't know how many bytes are in the array. If I replace ```public byte[] pbCrlEncoded;``` with ```public IntPtr pbCrlEncoded;``` I seem to get meaningful results from the rest of the script - the output here is ```27 June 2022 09:30:46``` and ```24 December 2022 17:50:46``` which are UTC times I get from the CRL in Crypto Shell Extensions...

Comment: ... (remove the ```[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=2)]``` as well

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately, the [PKI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/) module from Microsoft does not have any cmdlet that support this operation and the [PSPKI](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSPKI/) module from the PowerShell Gallery has been made by a third party, which I cannot use in this implementation.

Comment: @mclayton thanks a lot! you're absolutely right. I must have polluted my test environment during development: I've just rerun the snippet and it gives back the expected values.